# How to execute map, filter, flatMap using multiple threads in RxScala/Java?

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-scala

How to run `filter`, `map` and `flatMap` on `Observable` using multiple threads:

```
  def withDelay[T](delay: Duration)(t: => T) = {
    Thread.sleep(delay.toMillis)
    t
  }

  Observable
    .interval(500 millisecond)
    .filter(x => {
      withDelay(1 second) { x % 2 == 0 }
    })
    .map(x => {
      withDelay(1 second) { x * x }
    }).subscribe(println(_))
```

The goal is to run filtering and transformation operations concurrently using multiple threads.

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1673 and this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaParallel

Comment: @david.mihola, yes I checked both of them and was able to execute `subscribe` block in multiple threads however I could not do that for map, flatMap and filter. I assume that I might call other API or get additional data from database while filtering or transforming thus I want to make sure that this code will be executed concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use Async.toAsync() on each operation.

It's on the package rxjava-async

[Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/start.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will process each item of collection in a different thread (rxjava3).

```
var collect = Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"))
                      .flatMap(v -> {
                         return Observable.just(v)
                                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                        .map(v1 -> {
                                            int time = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000);
                                            Thread.sleep(time);
                                            return String.format("processed-%s", v1);
                                        });
                      })
                      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                      .blockingStream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **observeOn** operator, which it will execute all the next operators in the specific thread defined after the operator has been set

```
       /**
 * Once that you set in your pipeline the observerOn all the next steps of your pipeline will be executed in another thread.
 * Shall print
 * First step main
 * Second step RxNewThreadScheduler-2
 * Third step RxNewThreadScheduler-1
 */
@Test
public void testObservableObserverOn() throws InterruptedException {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(1)
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("First step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Second step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println( "Third step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .subscribe();
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

More async examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

Comment: Yes, but if you use .doOnNext() you can't do operations like map, flat, etc. It's only accept actions.

Comment: It's an example, you should be able to use whatever operator